# how to ask the user if they want the code to start again

Tags: python

I am just starting out on a python Nat5 course so I'm sorry if the answer is glaringly obvious but what I'm trying to do is ask the user if they want the code to restart or not and ask again if the user inputs an incorrect answer

```
print("would you like to ask again?")
go = input("enter yes/y or no/n")

if(go == 'y') or (go == 'yes'):
#replay here
elif(go == 'n') or (go == 'no'):
    exit()
else:
print("It's a yes or no question")
#ask to replay again
```

Comment: Read about loops.

Comment: You want to use a [`while` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is the best practice, but it works for me and I have had no issues.
Put the code in a function

```
def code():
    #insert the code here
```

and then call the function

```
if (go=='y'):
   code()
```

It is also worth noting that you will need to also call the function at the end of the code so that it actually runs the first time round.

Comment: that has solved my issue perfectly thanks a bunch mate